# Rest APIs : Howto release new API version without taking existing down

Tags: api

I have created a system which is live and I feel it should have minimal downtime.
But when I release the API I have to take the system down for few minutes.

Is there any architecture or way of implementation where we can have minimum down time.

Comment: Add a number to your API? `/api/v1/` / `/api/v2/`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add some more information regarding your setup to get better answers. One of solution would be to have isolated applications for each version of the API, thus you can add a new version without affecting the older ones.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonny.But if I create isolated applications lets say for 10 versions, I have to fix a bug in all 10 versions.